# Decoupling Capacitor Calculation

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, power-electronics, component-selection

I have few questions related to the schematics(BBB_SCH) sheet 2 in [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7UkEPGp8khcalRrM2p6QjQzXzQ)

1. There is a bulk decoupling capacitor of `10uF,10V` connected to the pin `10(AC)` of the PMIC [tps65217.pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65217.pdf). Can some one please explain how is this value calculated now I know  `C = I * dt/dv` but where in the data sheet can I find I , dt , dv.
2. There is a 100K ohm register R1 on the INT pin number 45. Can some one please let me know how is this value calculated.
3. Also on sheet 3 there is a `SN74AUC1G74` which is connected to the CEC Clock for HDMI Framer. Can some please let me know is this a clock for the HDMI.

Regards

Nick

Comment: You need to change the title to: Decoupling capacitor calculation, pull-up resistor selection, and flip flop (basics of electrical engineering).

Comment: Possible duplication of : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/decoupling-capacitors-what-size-and-how-many and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23645/how-do-i-calculate-the-required-value-for-a-pull-up-resistor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The input Capacitor should not be a critical value component. The datasheet recommends a typical value of 4.7uF, but others may be used. Since there's a lot of 10uF/10V around there, they may used one on this pin too to reduce BOM items.
2. Again, seems to be nota a critical value, just a pull-up resistor. Those usually range from a few Kilo-ohms to hundred ones. The 100k value appears in the 9.2 Functional Block Diagram on the datasheet.
3. Certainly it's a clock. Its role you will need to find in the datasheets of the components involved. Given the pin name of the [TDA19988](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/NXP_TDA19988.pdf), I would guess it is only some kind of system clock for it.