# How do smaller capacitors filter out higher frequencies than larger values?

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor

I commonly see 0.1 µF used on IC pins for decoupling. I occasionally see 0.01 µF and 0.001 µF capacitors used for filtering out higher frequencies. Is that incorrect, because I thought the impedance would increase at a fixed frequency if my capacitance decreased?

Meaning the higher frequencies would go into the IC or device you are filtering.

Comment: One word (acronym): ESL

Comment: Related link: Relevant information is given in some answers to this previous question: "[Decoupling capacitors: what size and how many?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2262/101852)"

Comment: Related: [Mr. EEVBlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_L._Jones_(video_blogger)) made a video about it: *[EEVblog #859 - Bypass Capacitor Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcJ6UdDx1vg)*

Comment: ESL is ambiguous (e.g., it is not *English as a second language*): [equivalent series inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_inductance)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If *practical* capacitors were purely capacitive, then indeed, a larger capacitor would do an even better (or at least "as good") job of filtering high frequencies as a smaller value one.

But capacitors are not purely capacitive; ones we can practically build are also unfortunately inductive, and at some frequency the inductive behavior dominates over the capacitive one, and they are no longer useful as shunt elements for filtering.

It happens that the construction of low-value capacitors puts the point where they become more inductive than capacitive at a higher frequency than the construction of high-value capacitors.

As a result you tend to see low value, low inductance capacitors (ideally in physically small packages) very close to IC pin pairs to handle high frequency needs, and a few higher value capacitors slightly more remote to handle low frequency ones.  In terms of low frequency analysis they are all in parallel, but in terms of AC analysis with the implicit self inductances, only the small local capacitors are meaningfully in-circuit at the highest frequencies.

Comment: Can you expand on how this happens practically comparing tantalum, ceramic and aluminium?

Comment: Only ceramic are even relevant to such a usage, and only the low values ones.  Presumably the geometric complexity (and physical size) of the higher value MLCC's is their undoing at high frequency.  I have to admit I haven't personally been baking them from exotic clay in my kitchen.

Comment: This is actually mostly a package size thing for MLCCs, 0402 have lower ESL then 0603, then 0201 are better then 0402 and so on. Within a series ESL is to a first order mostly independent of value.

Answer (score 8):

Capacitors aren’t perfect. They have a parasitic series inductance (equalvalent series inductance, or ESL) which forms, with the capacitance, an LC filter which has a resonance point.

- below the resonance, impedance decreases with frequency (behavior is capacitive)
- at resonance, impedance is at minimum
- above the resonance, impedance increases with frequency (behavior is inductive)

Smaller-value capacitors have higher resonance points because they have lower ESL, making them better for high frequency bypassing.

The construction of the cap can also reduce the ESL and thus improve high-frequency performance. Examples of low-ESL cap types include reverse-aspect, multi-terminal, and feedthrough.

Finally, the placement and connection of the cap affects the inductance too. Long traces add to the cap's own ESL, shifting the resonance point down and increasing impedance at high frequencies. To avoid this, the smaller, high-frequency caps are placed closest to the noise source.

This Murata appnote explains this in more detail.

[https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/emc/emifil/c39e.ashx](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/emc/emifil/c39e.ashx)

Answer (score 4):

If the capacitors were ideal, there would be no way that smaller value capacitors could filter better at higher frequencies.

But every ceramic cap maintains a capacitor-like behavior up to some frequency. Then the parasitic inductance starts to assert itself and ultimately, at high frequencies, dominate the impedance characteristic.

So basically capacitors turn into inductors at higher frequencies. In SOME CASES a 0.01uF might have lower impedance at some high frequencies than a 0.1uF capacitor.

When comparing capacitors with similar dielectric and the same package size, the larger value capacitor will usually have lower impedance even at very high frequencies, although many people continue to advocate using a range of values of capacitor to provide wideband decoupling.

Answer (score 0):

A decoupling capacitor is a specific application. Its purpose is not so much 'filtering' high frequencies going into the IC, but to provide local charge storage for the IC.

Especially with CMOS ICs, current pulses are drawn from the power supply when the logic gates change state - the MOSFET gates need to be charged and discharged. Whilst the average power consumption is low, the dynamic (i.e., peak) consumption is high. The bypass capacitor provides the local source for these peak currents. As current flows in a loop, to minimise the effect of the inductance of the power supply wiring, the decoupling capacitor should be placed as close as practicable to the IC.

As others have described, no capacitor is 'perfect'. Each different type of capacitor has its particular traits that makes it suitable or not suitable for a specific application. E.g., a capacitor that is ideal for decoupling may not be a good choice for use in an audio chain.

Answer (score -1):

For considerable enlightenment, examine the X2Y capacitors, which have FOUR terminals.

Some of those reach inductances of 200 picoHenries.

You cannot just throw X2Y capacitors into a circuit or PCB.

You must take responsibility for careful and insightful PCB design.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, for capacitance and frequency/ripples it couples, are inversely proportional and you can check out the formula and details on googling more on that.

So, in order to provide smooth power without ripples, we usually, connect the capacitor across the voltage rails and ground. And it will be placed near to the IC power pin /something like that as even the distance between the capacitor and IC pin can introduce copper trace resistance and thereby causing an RC delay in coupling the ripple which may result in a bit noisy rail. So, whenever the ripple / noise are there, the capacitor couples that to ground and while the voltage rail remains a smoother one.

In another case, we may put the capacitor as a series one in data and clock lines for some high speed lines like PCIe, SATA, etc., especially, in a point where we may connect the SSD or some other device to another device. This is because, to block the DC thing, but to couple the AC togglings. (In some devices, they may add some DC offset so that the data loss can be avoided (or) in some other noises which are in different frequencies may be avoided).

So, based on the speed of the interface, the capacitor capacitance will be.

And mostly for IC power pins, it will be available in a datasheet like this much capacitance is required at the input pins and this much at the output pins.

Comment: it is the inductance between the ic and the decoupling capacitor that we wish to minimise. Resistance is a factor, but the inductance is what becomes significant at higher frequencies. You could have a low resistance pcb trace with significant inductance that would make the decoupling capacitor useless.

Comment: What is an *"AC toggling"*?